# fotorama jquery - how to add external links to images, for certain galleries only

Tags: jquery, fotorama

I am running a "magazine website" where posts have preview galleries, and subscribers have access to full posts galleries.  All aglleries are displayed using Fotorama.

For the preview galleries, I want to be able to add a CLICK to URL on the gallerie images (ie: click to the subscribe page).  But I want those links to only be active on the preview galleries, and not on the full post galleries.

Is there a way to add a code in the tag of the wp-gallery so that fotorama will understand there is a click link on these specific gallery images?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code and what you have tried?

Comment: I use the standard WP gallery shortcode in my posts, and fotorama plugin converts them.
ie.:


[gallery ids="33429,33430,33431,33432,33433,33434,33435,33436,33437,33438,33439,33440,33441,33442,33443,33444,33445,33446,33447,33427"]

I didn't add any fotorama function to the wp gallery shortcode simply because I don't know if image linking to a url is possible or not... and if it is, what that ode would be.